# How to set read_only dynamically in django rest framework?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to check if the user id not equal to 1 then he should not be able to update few fields. I tried something similar to the following code but it did not work because of the following issues

1. `self.user.id` don't actually return the user I need to get the authenticated user in different why?
2. the def function maybe should have a different name like `update`?
3. also the general way maybe wrong?

```
class ForAdmins(serializers.ModelSerializer)):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

class ForUsers(serializers.ModelSerializer)):

    class Meta:
        read_only_fields = ['email','is_role_veryfied','is_email_veryfied']
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

class UsersSerializer(QueryFieldsMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def customize_read_only(self, instance, validated_data):
        if (self.user.id==1):
           return ForAdmins
        else:
           return ForUsers

    class Meta:
        # read_only_fields = ['username']
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: I prefer to put that logic in the view (get_serializer) and return the correct serializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the decision which serializer you want to pass from your views
or
you can do it inside modelSerializer update method.

for getting user from Serializer class Try:

```
    request = self.context.get('request', None)
    if request:
        user = request.user
```

for getting user from View class Try:

```
    user = self.request.user
```